# how to display data between two specific dates with date format as timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display data from table between two specific dates, date format is timestamp.

This query is working fine without dates.

```
 SELECT table1.username,COUNT(table2.userid) as total FROM table2  INNER JOIN table1 
ON table1.userid = table2.userid GROUP BY table1.username 
      ORDER BY COUNT(table2.userid) DESC
```

I am using below query to get data between two specific dates. but it does not display anything

```
    SELECT table1.username,COUNT(table2.userid) as total FROM table2  
    WHERE table2.date between '2015-01-0' and '2015-01-30'  INNER JOIN table1 ON 
table1.userid = table2.userid GROUP BY table1.username 
      ORDER BY COUNT(table2.userid) DESC
```

Comment: Did you actually write `between '2015-01-0' and '2015-01-30'` in your code, or is that a typo in your question? Between is inclusive, you should give it dates that exist on both ends.

Comment: @AirThomas there are the sample dates...  this query works fine if i do it like this :SELECT * FROM table WHERE  date between '2015-01-0' and '2015-01-30'. 

I need to get usernames so i want to make it work the way mentioned above

Comment: `'2015-01-0'` isn't a valid date... Did you mean `'2015-01-1'`?

Comment: @machavity its does not either this way '2015-01-10'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT table1.username,COUNT(table2.userid) as total 
FROM table2  
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.userid = table2.userid 
WHERE table2.date between '2015-01-0' and '2015-01-30'
GROUP BY table1.username 
  ORDER BY COUNT(table2.userid) DESC
```

I Guess we cannot use where clause before writing join.

Comment: This has worked. Would you like to explain this behaviour of WHERE clause, why it did not work the first place ???

Comment: because you were writing JOIN statement after it which is wrong. First we write all the JOIN statements and then write where clause. By writing in your way, you need to write that as a SubQuery like `Select T1.name,T2.id From (Select * from Table2 where date between '2015-01-0' and '2015-01-30') as T2 INNER JOIN Table1 as T1 .... ` Please upvote if my answer helped :)

Comment: Just changing the postion of where has helped